# Open a Form with properties set in design mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I created and designed 2 Forms in Visual Studio: `frmMain` and `frmSub`.
By "designed" I mean I used the properties window to set several properties like `MaximizeBox = false` and `ShowInTaskbar = false`.

Now, when I set this code to a Button click event, these properties are ignored:

```
using (Form frmSub = new Form())
{
    if (frmSub .ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         // Some code...
    }
}
```

I do understand I am creating a new instance of the Form and have to set the properties as mentioned again programmatically.

Is there a way to open the Form using the pre-set properties?

Comment: Is this your real code? Form is the base class. You have created an instance of the base class and named it frmSub. To create an instance of the class frmSub you should have _frmSub finstance = new frmSub()_

Comment: "I do understand I am creating a new instance of the form and have to set the properties as mentioned again programmatically.". **No, you don't**. The properties you set are already in the partial implementation of your class, you don't need to set up the properties programatically. You are probably missing something else.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks you. Changed it to "using (Form frmSub = new frmSub ())"

Comment: one comment on that: if you declare the variable as the base class, you wont natively have access to any custom properties you have on the form. youd need to cast it to the subclass in order to have access to those properties.

Comment: *Changed it to `using (Form frmSub = new frmSub())`*. You didn't read well what Steve wrote. You need to create an instance of the Form you designed, not a generic one. So: `using (frmSub frmSubInstance = new frmSub())`. Give `frmSubInstance` the name you want.